# Fail to use javascript to valid checkbox and radio in form

Tags: javascript, html

I want the Form to pop up without input or selection of values and to prevent page breaks (when clicking submit). However, when I used only function `check(myForm)`, I was able to successfully pop up and prevent the page jump after clicking submit (when nothing was filled in and selected). But when I add function `checkButons(FRM)`, click submit (when nothing has been filled in and selected) and the page jumps right to it.

I used to have two radio stations, so it works. But when I replaced it with a checkbox, it didn't work.

**Following is my code**

```js
<script>
function check(myForm){
     if (myForm.username.value==""){
         window.alert("Required field Name is empty.\n");
         return false;}
  if (myForm.vehicleregistration.value==""){
         window.alert("Required field Vehicle Registration is empty.\n");
         return false;}
  if (myForm.type[].length == 0){
         window.alert("Required field Vehsdsdle Registration is empty.\n");
         return false;}
  else {return true;}
}


// checks buttons (radio, checkbox) - coursesweb.net 
function checkButons(frm) { 
 var re = false; // used to determine when a button is checked 
 var err = ''; // to store the errors 
 
 var type = frm.type; // contains an array with all radio buttons 'vegetable' 
 
 // create an Array in JSonn format with checkbox buttons 
 var days = frm.days; 
 
 // traverse the radio buttons 
 // if one is checked sets re to true, and stops the iteration with 'break' 
 for(var i=0; i<type.length; i++) { 
 if(type[i].checked == true) { 
 re = true; 
 break; 
 } 
 } 
 
 // if 're' is false means no radio button checked, add error in 'err'  
 if(re == false) err += '- You must check at least one vegetable'; 
 
 // make 're' again False, and traverse the checkbox buttons 
 // if one is checked sets re to true, and stops the iteration with 'break' 
 re = false 
 for(var i=0; i<days.length; i++) { 
 if(days[i].checked == true) { 
 re = true; 
 break; 
 } 
 } 
 
 // if 're' is false means no checkbox button checked, add error in 'err'  
 if (re == false) err += '\n - You must check at least one fruit'; 
 
 // if 'err' not empty, alert the error(s) and returns False to stop submitting form 
 if(err != '') { 
 alert(err); 
 return false; 
 } 
 else return re; 
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Parking Permit Application</title>
</body> 
</html>





</head>
<body>

<h1>Parking Permit Application</h1>
<p>If you would like to apply for a parking permit, please enter your details into the form below.</p>

</body> 

<form method="post" name="ass" action="q3.php" onsubmit="return check(this), checkButons(this)">

<table>
  <tr>
  <td><div>Name:</div></td>
          
 <td><input name="username" type="text"></td> <br>
     </tr>
        <tr>
  <td><div>Vehicle Registration:</div></td>
        <td>  
 <input name="vehicleregistration" type="text"> <br></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><div>Vehicle Type:</div></td>
    <td> 
 <input name="type[]" type="radio" value="Car">Car
 <input name="type[]" type="radio" value="Van">Van
 <input name="type[]" type="radio" value="Bike">Bike
     </td>
  </tr>
        
  <tr>
        <td><div>Day:</div></td>
        <td>  
 <input name="days[]" type="checkbox" value="Monday" >M
 <input name="days[]" type="checkbox" value="Tuesday">Tu
 <input name="days[]" type="checkbox" value="Wednsday">W
 <input name="days[]" type="checkbox" value="Thursday">Th
 <input name="days[]" type="checkbox" value="Friday">F
 <br>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
        <td><div>Priority Cases:</div></td>
        <td>  
 <select name="prioritycases">
 <option selected="">-</option>
 <option value="Child in nursery">Child in nursery</option>
 <option value="Blue badge holder">Blue badge holder</option>
 <option value="Work van">Work van</option>
 <option value="Professor">Professor</option>
 </select><br>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <div id="msg"></div>
 <td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sub"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
</html>
```

Please help me to see what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Leslie :)

I am going to rewrite your code a little bit to show you better practice.

```
function check() {
    if (document.querySelector('[name="username"]').value==""){
      alert("Required field Name is empty.\n");
      this.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    if (doucment.querySelector('[name="vehicleregistration"]').value==""){
      alert("Required field Vehicle Registration is empty.\n");
      return false;
    }
    if (document.querySelectorAll('[name="type[]"]:checked').length == 0){
      alert("Required field Vehsdsdle Registration is empty.\n");
      return false;
    }
    if(document.querySelectorAll('[name="days[]"]:checked').length == 0){
        alert("Must select at least one day.");
      return false;
    }

    return true; //It will hit here if none of the if statements are true
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Matthew.
But it still doesn't work. Here's the situation: only one 'Required field Name is empty.' pops up. Then the page cannot be prevented from jumping to the next page. But when I delete the two parts' [name=" username"] 'and' [name="vehicleregistration"] ', the remaining raido and checkbox will work. I don't know what happened. But in the end, my task was completed with your help, because I used the method of 'required' in the first two parts. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You're welcome, but I am not quite sure what you mean by it doesn't work. I ran it on my end and it prevents the form from submitting when it wasn't filled out. Any reason why you're not using the form validation that is built in?

Comment: Here's how it goes: when I don't fill anything on the page and click submit, it just only pops up with a popover that asks me to enter my name. Then the page jumps. Instead of waiting to fill in all the blanks before jumping.
But after I remove the validation of the two text properties, the rest of the radio and checkbox can be validated successfully.